# Is it possible to read coredata(sqlite) of the installed app in iphone from xcode?

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

I accidentally deleted core data file from xcode. But before deleting happened, I debugged the app on my iphone. so my iphone would have the lost data of sqlite.

Is it possible to somehow read the data inside sqlite(=core data) that my iphone's installed app has?

Comment: so you are't using source version control (GIT) then? you really should... do you mean the xcdatamodeld file or an sqlite file?

Comment: @Wain, Im not quite sure what GIT is. I meant the sqlite file with ".sqlite". Just like how I can access .sqlite files of iOS simulator, I was wondering if I could do the same from iphones -> access app's .sqlite file of iphone.

Comment: go and find out what GIT is before you do anything else. then start using it before you do anything else. then use an app like ifunbox to look at the files on your device.